# How to uninstall a program installed by another user that is not accessible anymore?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall

I installed a program A with a userid B but recently, my computer (Windows 10) joined our company domain and I got new userid C. Since then, I can't login my computer with the old userid B because of domain policy. Now I want to uninstall the program A, but there is no such item in Programs & Features in Control Panel although corresponding installation folder is in Program Files.

How can I uninstall the program?

Comment: Just manually run the uninstaller of program A, which is inside of the installation folder?

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm Unfortunately, it does not have uninstaller.

Comment: Please leave the reason for the downvote. Otherwise, there is no improvement I can make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this program a Microsoft Store App? If so, you can try to use PowerShell Commands  "Get-AppxPackage" to check the program info and then use "Remove-AppxPackage -Package  -AllUsers" to uninstall it. I have tested it on my own Windows 10, after login with another user, command "Remove-AppxPackage -Package ” will report “Package was not found”. But with an additional “-AllUsers”, the command performed successfully to uninstall the app Facebook, it disappeared in the output of "Get-AppxPackage". 
[image]
[image]
Besides, generally can’t find the uninstall program of a software divided into several scenarios:

1.It's green software use without installation. If you want to clean it up, you don't need to uninstall it, just delete the folder where it resides.

2.It's malware, or malicious software. If this is the case, it is necessary to use anti-virus software to scan.

3.A less likely scenario, some software editors may inadvertently forget to write the uninstall program, usually private or amateur programmers will appear in this situation, the solution is the same as the green software.

4.You can also try to check if the program can be opened and working fine, sometimes software that does not have an uninstall program in the source file is corrupt. Simply delete the source file.

5. Also some software may be providing a Repair/Uninstall option, you can try to uninstall it by clicking the install software.

Hope to help you. If there is anything else we can do for you, please feel free to post in the forum. Thank you for choosing Microsoft.

Best regards,

Zoe Mo

Answer (score 2):

First, Programs & Features display is not dependent on the user.

Second, unfortunately some badly behaved programs leave no entries in Programs & Features.

As no uninstaller is supplied in the installation folder, you will need to manually delete all files and registry entries, by searching for identifying strings in the disk
file names and in regedit.

Comment: Programs and Features display is dependent on User. If a program is installed in "Only for Me" mode by a user, it will not show up under Programs and Features for other users.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with third party software in such cases. Manually removing files and registry entries is time consuming. 
Perhaps try [Geek](https://geekuninstaller.com/) uninstaller.